# Using Python Multiprocessing to Write to CSV

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'd like to utilize multiprocessing to create a single csv file in parallel, but so far the result is wonky. I have created a nested list that should have a dimension of 50 by 10 when a serialization is performed without multiprocessing. But, the csv file produced contains each list being an element. How should I fix this?

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def sample(key):
    sample_list = [[34 for i in range(10)] for i in range(50)] 
    return sample_list

pool = Pool(processes=2) # Number of cores I'm using
resultset = pool.imap(sample, list(range(25)), chunksize=25)

with open('./testing.csv','w') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
    for result in resultset:
        for row in result:
            writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: do you mean `writer.writerow(row)`?

Comment: Yes. That was a typo. But, now a new issue emerged. The sample_list is being copied 25times.

Comment: That sounds right, because of list(range(25)) means you get back a set of 25 results (each 50x10). Perhaps you can clarify your original question by adding what you want the csv to look like?